# Why can’t I seem to run a VM via virt-install from the command line in macOS?

Tags: macos, qemu, libvirt, virt-manager

I try to run VM with emulation on MacBook 14 M1 Pro on macOS Monterey (12.3.1). I installed libvirt 8.2.0 and virt-manager 4.0.0 via brew.

I used this formula for virt-manager:

```
class VirtManager < Formula
  include Language::Python::Virtualenv

  desc "Desktop tool for managing virtual machines via libvirt"
  homepage "https://virt-manager.org/"
  url "https://releases.pagure.org/virt-manager/virt-manager-4.0.0.tar.gz"
  sha256 "515aaa2021a4bf352b0573098fe6958319b1ba8ec508ea37e064803f97f17086"
  license "GPL-2.0-or-later"
  head "https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager.git"

  depends_on "docutils" => :build
  depends_on "gettext" => :build
  depends_on "adwaita-icon-theme"
  depends_on "cdrtools"
  depends_on "glib"
  depends_on "gtk+3"
  depends_on "gtk-vnc"
  depends_on "gtksourceview4"
  depends_on "libosinfo"
  depends_on "libvirt"
  depends_on "libvirt-glib"
  depends_on "libxml2"
  depends_on "pygobject3"
  depends_on "python"
  depends_on "spice-gtk"
  depends_on "vte3"

  # To update:
  #
  #     cd "$(mktemp -d)" &&
  #         python3 -m venv venv &&
  #         . venv/bin/activate &&
  #         pip install libvirt-python argcomplete requests homebrew-pypi-poet &&
  #         poet libvirt-python -a argcomplete -a requests &&
  #         deactivate &&
  #         rm -Rf venv
  resource "argcomplete" do
    url "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/f8/67851ae4fe5396ba6868c5d84219b81ea6a5d53991a6853616095c30adc0/argcomplete-2.0.0.tar.gz"
    sha256 "6372ad78c89d662035101418ae253668445b391755cfe94ea52f1b9d22425b20"
  end

    resource "certifi" do
    url "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/ae/d26450834f0acc9e3d1f74508da6df1551ceab6c2ce0766a593362d6d57f/certifi-2021.10.8.tar.gz"
    sha256 "78884e7c1d4b00ce3cea67b44566851c4343c120abd683433ce934a68ea58872"
  end

  resource "charset-normalizer" do
    url "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/31/7bcaf657fafb3c6db8c787a865434290b726653c912085fbd371e9b92e1c/charset-normalizer-2.0.12.tar.gz"
    sha256 "2857e29ff0d34db842cd7ca3230549d1a697f96ee6d3fb071cfa6c7393832597"
  end

  resource "idna" do
    url "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/08/e3fc7c8161090f742f504f40b1bccbfc544d4a4e09eb774bf40aafce5436/idna-3.3.tar.gz"
    sha256 "9d643ff0a55b762d5cdb124b8eaa99c66322e2157b69160bc32796e824360e6d"
  end

  resource "libvirt-python" do
    url "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/50/cf/3703fc97df6292c9c0ac8b828a85ca11f492f7bffd190f191ea7484024ed/libvirt-python-8.2.0.tar.gz"
    sha256 "f8b8cea67ff0d64d63029cc3410a4656e04ee9f26837a856bc0c287da55d053a"
  end

  resource "pycairo" do
    url "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/a4/506564f574fa74c90b98690e8ecc8dbae1629f31fcfe0be69de45d9e1605/pycairo-1.21.0.tar.gz"
    sha256 "251907f18a552df938aa3386657ff4b5a4937dde70e11aa042bc297957f4b74b"
  end

  resource "requests" do
    url "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/f3/26ff3767f099b73e0efa138a9998da67890793bfa475d8278f84a30fec77/requests-2.27.1.tar.gz"
    sha256 "68d7c56fd5a8999887728ef304a6d12edc7be74f1cfa47714fc8b414525c9a61"
  end

  resource "urllib3" do
    url "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/a5/4eab74853625505725cefdf168f48661b2cd04e7843ab836f3f63abf81da/urllib3-1.26.9.tar.gz"
    sha256 "aabaf16477806a5e1dd19aa41f8c2b7950dd3c746362d7e3223dbe6de6ac448e"
  end

  def install
    venv = virtualenv_create(libexec, "python3")
    venv.pip_install resources

    # virt-manager uses distutils, so we can't use Homebrew's helper methods
    args = %w[
      --no-user-cfg
      --no-update-icon-cache
      --no-compile-schemas
    ]
    # virt-manager requires --prefix to match between `configure` and `install`
    system "#{libexec}/bin/python3", "setup.py", *args,
      "configure", "--prefix=#{libexec}", "--default-hvs", "qemu,lxc"
    system "#{libexec}/bin/python3", "setup.py", *args,
      "install", "--prefix=#{libexec}"
    bin.install_symlink Dir["#{libexec}/bin/virt-*"]
    share.install Dir["#{libexec}/share/{bash-completion,glib-2.0,icons,locale,man}"]
  end

  def post_install
    system "#{Formula["glib"].opt_bin}/glib-compile-schemas", "#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/share/glib-2.0/schemas"
    system "#{Formula["gtk+3"].opt_bin}/gtk3-update-icon-cache", "-f", "-t", "#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/share/icons/hicolor"
  end

  test do
    system "#{bin}/virt-manager", "--version"
  end
end
```

Arguments for starting VM:

```
virt-install --name guest1-rocky8_5 --memory 4096 --vcpus 4 --disk work_space/packer/rocky8_5.qcow2 --qemu-commandline='-netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 -device e1000e,netdev=net0 -accel tcg' --import --virt-type qemu --arch x86_64 --os-variant rhel8.0 -d
```

And I got the following output:

```
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:05 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (cli:204) Launched with command line: /opt/homebrew/bin/virt-install --name guest1-rocky8_5 --memory 4096 --vcpus 4 --disk workspace/packer/rocky8_5.qcow2 --qemu-commandline=-netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 -device e1000e,netdev=net0 -accel tcg --import --virt-type qemu --arch x86_64 --os-variant rhel8.0 -d
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:05 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (virtinstall:212) Distilled --network options: ['default']
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:05 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (virtinstall:142) Distilled --disk options: ['workspace/packer/rocky8_5.qcow2']
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:05 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (cli:216) Requesting libvirt URI default
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:05 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (cli:219) Received libvirt URI qemu:///session
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:05 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (guest:330) Setting Guest osinfo name <_OsVariant name=generic>
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:05 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (guest:330) Setting Guest osinfo name <_OsVariant name=rhel8.0>
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:05 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (installer:542) No media for distro detection.
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:05 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (installer:544) installer.detect_distro returned=None
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:05 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (osdict:216) No recommended value found for key='n-cpus', using minimum=1 * 2
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:05 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (guest:535) Prefer EFI => False
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:05 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (graphics:157) App is configured with default_graphics=spice
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:05 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (graphics:167) spice requested but HV doesn't support it. Using vnc.
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:05 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (guest:1094) Using num_pcie_root_ports=14
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:06 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (disk:236) DeviceDisk.check_path_search path=/Users/alexey/workspace/packer/rocky8_5.qcow2
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:06 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (cli:265)
Starting install...
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:06 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (installer:587) Generated initial_xml: None required
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:06 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (installer:589) Generated final_xml:
<domain type="qemu">
  <name>guest1-rocky8_5</name>
  <uuid>c9af9024-c29b-411c-b36c-ff9e9073f95a</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://redhat.com/rhel/8.0"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="q35">hvm</type>
    <boot dev="hd"/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <clock offset="utc">
    <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
    <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
    <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
  </clock>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/opt/homebrew/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
      <source file="/Users/alexey/workspace/packer/rocky8_5.qcow2"/>
      <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
    </disk>
    <controller type="usb" model="qemu-xhci" ports="15"/>
    <controller type="pci" model="pcie-root"/>
    <controller type="pci" model="pcie-root-port"/>
    <controller type="pci" model="pcie-root-port"/>
    <controller type="pci" model="pcie-root-port"/>
    <controller type="pci" model="pcie-root-port"/>
    <controller type="pci" model="pcie-root-port"/>
    <controller type="pci" model="pcie-root-port"/>
    <controller type="pci" model="pcie-root-port"/>
    <controller type="pci" model="pcie-root-port"/>
    <controller type="pci" model="pcie-root-port"/>
    <controller type="pci" model="pcie-root-port"/>
    <controller type="pci" model="pcie-root-port"/>
    <controller type="pci" model="pcie-root-port"/>
    <controller type="pci" model="pcie-root-port"/>
    <controller type="pci" model="pcie-root-port"/>
    <interface type="user">
      <mac address="52:54:00:d8:a2:6d"/>
      <model type="virtio"/>
    </interface>
    <console type="pty"/>
    <channel type="unix">
      <source mode="bind"/>
      <target type="virtio" name="org.qemu.guest_agent.0"/>
    </channel>
    <input type="tablet" bus="usb"/>
    <graphics type="vnc" port="-1"/>
    <video>
      <model type="virtio"/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model="virtio"/>
    <rng model="virtio">
      <backend model="random">/dev/urandom</backend>
    </rng>
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline xmlns:qemu="http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0">
    <qemu:arg value="-netdev"/>
    <qemu:arg value="user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-device"/>
    <qemu:arg value="e1000e,netdev=net0"/>
    <qemu:arg value="-accel"/>
    <qemu:arg value="tcg"/>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>

[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:06 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (installer:642) XML fetched from libvirt object:
<domain type='qemu' id='25' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
  <name>guest1-rocky8_5</name>
  <uuid>c9af9024-c29b-411c-b36c-ff9e9073f95a</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://redhat.com/rhel/8.0"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-6.2'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='full'>
    <model fallback='forbid'>qemu64</model>
    <feature policy='require' name='hypervisor'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='lahf_lm'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/opt/homebrew/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/Users/alexey/workspace/packer/rocky8_5.qcow2' index='1'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='qemu-xhci' ports='15'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pcie-root'>
      <alias name='pcie.0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='1' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='1' port='0x10'/>
      <alias name='pci.1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='2' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='2' port='0x11'/>
      <alias name='pci.2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='3' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='3' port='0x12'/>
      <alias name='pci.3'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='4' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='4' port='0x13'/>
      <alias name='pci.4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='5' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='5' port='0x14'/>
      <alias name='pci.5'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x4'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='6' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='6' port='0x15'/>
      <alias name='pci.6'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x5'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='7' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='7' port='0x16'/>
      <alias name='pci.7'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x6'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='8' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='8' port='0x17'/>
      <alias name='pci.8'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='9' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='9' port='0x18'/>
      <alias name='pci.9'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='10' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='10' port='0x19'/>
      <alias name='pci.10'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='11' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='11' port='0x1a'/>
      <alias name='pci.11'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='12' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='12' port='0x1b'/>
      <alias name='pci.12'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='13' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='13' port='0x1c'/>
      <alias name='pci.13'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x4'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='14' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='14' port='0x1d'/>
      <alias name='pci.14'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x5'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='sata' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1f' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <alias name='virtio-serial0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='user'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:d8:a2:6d'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/ttys004'/>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/ttys004'>
      <source path='/dev/ttys004'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='unix'>
      <source mode='bind' path='/Users/alexey/.config/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/domain-25-guest1-rocky8_5/org.qemu.guest_agent.0'/>
      <target type='virtio' name='org.qemu.guest_agent.0' state='disconnected'/>
      <alias name='channel0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input2'/>
    </input>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5900' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
    </graphics>
    <audio id='1' type='none'/>
    <video>
      <model type='virtio' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
    <rng model='virtio'>
      <backend model='random'>/dev/urandom</backend>
      <alias name='rng0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x06' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </rng>
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-netdev'/>
    <qemu:arg value='user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-device'/>
    <qemu:arg value='e1000e,netdev=net0'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-accel'/>
    <qemu:arg value='tcg'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>

[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:06 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (cli:383) Running: virt-viewer --connect qemu:///session --wait guest1-rocky8_5
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:06 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (cli:265) Running graphical console command: virt-viewer --connect qemu:///session --wait guest1-rocky8_5

(virt-viewer:58588): virt-viewer-WARNING **: 01:52:06.563: (../src/virt-viewer-window.c:831):accel_key_to_keys: runtime check failed: ((accel_mods & ~(GDK_SHIFT_MASK | GDK_CONTROL_MASK | GDK_MOD1_MASK)) == 0)

(virt-viewer:58588): virt-viewer-WARNING **: 01:52:06.563: (../src/virt-viewer-window.c:831):accel_key_to_keys: runtime check failed: ((accel_mods & ~(GDK_SHIFT_MASK | GDK_CONTROL_MASK | GDK_MOD1_MASK)) == 0)

(virt-viewer:58588): virt-viewer-WARNING **: 01:52:06.563: (../src/virt-viewer-window.c:831):accel_key_to_keys: runtime check failed: ((accel_mods & ~(GDK_SHIFT_MASK | GDK_CONTROL_MASK | GDK_MOD1_MASK)) == 0)

(virt-viewer:58588): virt-viewer-WARNING **: 01:52:06.563: (../src/virt-viewer-window.c:831):accel_key_to_keys: runtime check failed: ((accel_mods & ~(GDK_SHIFT_MASK | GDK_CONTROL_MASK | GDK_MOD1_MASK)) == 0)

(virt-viewer:58588): virt-viewer-WARNING **: 01:52:06.563: (../src/virt-viewer-window.c:831):accel_key_to_keys: runtime check failed: ((accel_mods & ~(GDK_SHIFT_MASK | GDK_CONTROL_MASK | GDK_MOD1_MASK)) == 0)

(virt-viewer:58588): virt-viewer-WARNING **: 01:52:06.563: (../src/virt-viewer-window.c:831):accel_key_to_keys: runtime check failed: ((accel_mods & ~(GDK_SHIFT_MASK | GDK_CONTROL_MASK | GDK_MOD1_MASK)) == 0)
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:10 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (cli:255)   File "/opt/homebrew/bin/virt-install", line 8, in <module>
    virtinstall.runcli()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/virtinstall.py", line 1220, in runcli
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/virtinstall.py", line 1213, in main
    start_install(guest, installer, options)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/virtinstall.py", line 961, in start_install
    fail(e, do_exit=False)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/cli.py", line 255, in fail
    log.debug("".join(traceback.format_stack()))

[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:10 virt-install 58583] ERROR (cli:256) operation failed: cannot read cputime for domain
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:10 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (cli:258)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/virtinstall.py", line 949, in start_install
    _process_domain(domain, guest, installer,
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/virtinstall.py", line 900, in _process_domain
    _wait_for_domain(installer, instdomain, autoconsole, waithandler)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/virtinstall.py", line 837, in _wait_for_domain
    if instdomain.check_inactive():
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/virtinstall.py", line 817, in check_inactive
    dominfo = self._domain.info()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1659, in info
    raise libvirtError('virDomainGetInfo() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: operation failed: cannot read cputime for domain 
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:52:10 virt-install 58583] DEBUG (cli:271) Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///session start guest1-rocky8_5
otherwise, please restart your installation.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///session start guest1-rocky8_5
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

If I add `--autoconsole text` I can see in output follow:

```
Creating domain...                                                                                                                                                                             |    0 B  00:00:00
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 02:08:07 virt-install 59096] DEBUG (cli:383) Running: virsh --connect qemu:///session console guest1-rocky8_5
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 02:08:07 virt-install 59096] DEBUG (cli:265) Running text console command: virsh --connect qemu:///session console guest1-rocky8_5
Running text console command: virsh --connect qemu:///session console guest1-rocky8_5
Connected to domain 'guest1-rocky8_5'
Escape character is ^] (Ctrl + ])
```

And nothing comes out.

If I try to SSH on port 5555 I get:

```
ssh localhost -p 5555
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by 127.0.0.1 port 5555
```

If cancel run:

```
Running text console command: virsh --connect qemu:///session console guest1-rocky8_5
Connected to domain 'guest1-rocky8_5'
Escape character is ^] (Ctrl + ])
^]
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 02:24:38 virt-install 59378] DEBUG (cli:255)   File "/opt/homebrew/bin/virt-install", line 8, in <module>
    virtinstall.runcli()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/virtinstall.py", line 1220, in runcli
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/virtinstall.py", line 1213, in main
    start_install(guest, installer, options)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/virtinstall.py", line 961, in start_install
    fail(e, do_exit=False)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/cli.py", line 255, in fail
    log.debug("".join(traceback.format_stack()))

[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 02:24:38 virt-install 59378] ERROR (cli:256) operation failed: cannot read cputime for domain
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 02:24:38 virt-install 59378] DEBUG (cli:258)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/virtinstall.py", line 949, in start_install
    _process_domain(domain, guest, installer,
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/virtinstall.py", line 900, in _process_domain
    _wait_for_domain(installer, instdomain, autoconsole, waithandler)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/virtinstall.py", line 837, in _wait_for_domain
    if instdomain.check_inactive():
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/virtinstall.py", line 817, in check_inactive
    dominfo = self._domain.info()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/virt-manager/4.0.0/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1659, in info
    raise libvirtError('virDomainGetInfo() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: operation failed: cannot read cputime for domain
[Sun, 10 Apr 2022 02:24:38 virt-install 59378] DEBUG (cli:271) Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///session start guest1-rocky8_5
otherwise, please restart your installation.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///session start guest1-rocky8_5
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

But if I try use only qemu-system-x86_64 it works well:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4G -machine type=q35,accel=tcg -smp 2 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 -device e1000e,netdev=net0 -drive file=workspace/packer/rocky8_5.qcow2,if=ide

ssh localhost -p 5555 cat /etc/redhat-release
root@localhost's password:
Rocky Linux release 8.5 (Green Obsidian)
```

I think that when I run VM within virt-install some arguments are added by default and that stops the VM from starting normally. Maybe I need to change **some arguments or add new ones** via virt-install in order for the VM to run correctly?

If I run VM within virt-manager with default parameters, I have been the same issue.

Despite running errors via virt-install or virt-manager, I can see this VM in libvirt:

```bash
virsh list
 Id   Name              State
---------------------------------
 1    guest1-rocky8_5   running
```

I can connect to this VM via VNC, but ssh on port 5555 not forwarding, as I wrote above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [converted](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_administration_guide/sub-sect-domain_commands-converting_qemu_arguments_to_domain_xml) command `qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4G -machine type=q35,accel=tcg -smp 2 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 -device e1000e,netdev=net0 -drive file=workspace/packer/rocky8_5.qcow2,if=ide` via `virsh domxml-from-native` to XML for libvirt and after that I defined VM.

*I used a docker container with an old version of libvirt to use `domxml-from-native`, because this operation is [not supported](https://docs.virtuozzo.com/libvirt-docs-5.6.0/html/drvqemu.html#xmlimport) since v5.5.0*

I can see this VM in virt-manager:[image: virt-manager]

If I click button to run VM it doesn't change state and I see the previous error in the log of virt-manager `(cannot read cputime for domain)`:

```bash
[Mon, 11 Apr 2022 14:03:48 virt-manager 5263] DEBUG (connection:631) domain lifecycle event: domain=unnamed state=VIR_DOMAIN_EVENT_DEFINED reason=VIR_DOMAIN_EVENT_DEFINED_ADDED
[Mon, 11 Apr 2022 14:03:48 virt-manager 5263] DEBUG (connection:1077) domain=unnamed status=Shutoff added
[Mon, 11 Apr 2022 14:05:25 virt-manager 5263] DEBUG (vmmenu:210) Starting vm 'unnamed'
[Mon, 11 Apr 2022 14:05:25 virt-manager 5263] DEBUG (connection:631) domain lifecycle event: domain=unnamed state=VIR_DOMAIN_EVENT_RESUMED reason=VIR_DOMAIN_EVENT_RESUMED_UNPAUSED
[Mon, 11 Apr 2022 14:05:25 virt-manager 5263] DEBUG (connection:631) domain lifecycle event: domain=unnamed state=VIR_DOMAIN_EVENT_STARTED reason=VIR_DOMAIN_EVENT_STARTED_BOOTED
[Mon, 11 Apr 2022 14:05:25 virt-manager 5263] DEBUG (libvirtobject:261) Error refreshing <vmmDomain name=unnamed id=0x10ae59b80> from events: operation failed: cannot read cputime for domain
[Mon, 11 Apr 2022 14:05:25 virt-manager 5263] DEBUG (libvirtobject:265) Scheduling priority tick with: {'force': True, 'pollvm': True}
[Mon, 11 Apr 2022 14:05:25 virt-manager 5263] DEBUG (libvirtobject:261) Error refreshing <vmmDomain name=unnamed id=0x10ae59b80> from events: operation failed: cannot read cputime for domain
[Mon, 11 Apr 2022 14:05:25 virt-manager 5263] DEBUG (libvirtobject:265) Scheduling priority tick with: {'force': True, 'pollvm': True}
```

But `virsh list` shows that VM is running and this time I can connect via SSH on port 5555:

```bash
 Id   Name      State
-------------------------
 8    unnamed   running

ssh localhost -p 5555 cat /etc/redhat-release
root@localhost's password:
Rocky Linux release 8.5 (Green Obsidian)
```

This looks like a issue with the **virDomainGetInfo** function and not the default parameters when I run VM via virt-install or virt-manager.

Also, the issue may be related to the **virConnectNodeDeviceEventRegisterAny** function because I can see error when running virt-manager:

```
[Mon, 11 Apr 2022 16:08:55 virt-manager 6759] DEBUG (connection:967) Connection doesn't seem to support nodedev APIs.
[Mon, 11 Apr 2022 16:08:55 virt-manager 6759] DEBUG (connection:739) Using domain events
[Mon, 11 Apr 2022 16:08:55 virt-manager 6759] DEBUG (connection:778) Using network events
[Mon, 11 Apr 2022 16:08:55 virt-manager 6759] DEBUG (connection:797) Using storage pool events
[Mon, 11 Apr 2022 16:08:55 virt-manager 6759] DEBUG (connection:825) Error registering node device events: this function is not supported by the connection driver: virConnectNodeDeviceEventRegisterAny
```

I opened [ticket](https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt-python/-/issues/12) in libvirt-python repo because virt-manager and virt-install use this library. And I also opened [ticket](https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt/-/issues/298) in the libvirt repo because I think this issue is directly related to the **virDomainGetInfo** function when it is called for the domain running under Apple M1 Pro CPU.

<s>**To summarize**: probably virt-manager cannot be used on macOS with an Apple Silicon M1 CPU.</s>

UPD: **This bug has been fixed**. See details in this [ticket](https://gitlab.com/libvirt/libvirt/-/issues/298).

Comment: Which docker image you used?

Comment: @RobertPro I built the image myself using the proper version of libvirt.